# Good MVVM Example of Adding a DataTable to a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I've very new to MVVM, I'm looking for a good example of adding a DataTable to a DataGrid using binding.

Every example I've looked at so far only uses view and viewmodel.

I want to create the DataTable in the model and then pass it to viewmodel and then update the view from there, is that the correct way to do it?

```
    public OleDbConnection connectionRun()
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\DB.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=Passw0rd";
        return con;
    }

    public DataTable dataTableFactory(String query)
    {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            OleDbConnection con = connectionRun();
            OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);

            OleDbCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
            dataAdapter.Fill(table);
            con.Close();
            return table;
        }
    }
```

That's the code I use to create the DataTable, I've got it working fine in WinForms but decided to try learn MVVM and WPF

Thanks!

Comment: When you want to learn ``MVVM`` dont do it wrong in the first place, a datatable shouldnt be used in the ``Model``, thats the reason you find it in the ``ViewModel`` at basically all examples. Give us a reason why you want it to be in the model.

Comment: My misunderstanding, I thought ViewModel was used purely to pass data from Models to Views. What should the Model be used for?

Comment: ``ViewModel`` is used to prepare the data (models) to make it accessable to the ``View``. The ``Model`` should basically be just a plain old clr object (POCO), nothing fancy in there.

Comment: So the above code would go in ViewModels?

Comment: I'd say yes, though I must admit, was thinking since you are using datatables, and want to use them directly what are your models actually? I use ``Entity Framwork`` when I do a ``MVVM`` application. ``EF`` is an ``ORM`` (Object-relational mapping) library, and with that you have your database as objects which represents your model structure. So for a ``Table`` lets say ``Customers`` in your ``DataTable`` you will get a class ``Custumer`` with its members being the columns in the table.

Comment: That sounds exactly what I'm looking for, thanks Random I'll have a look at that.